# Profiling help: slow matrix-scalar assignment

Tags: arrays, matlab, profiling

I'm micro-optimizing an inner loop and ran into something I don't understand in the profiler (R2013b):

[image: profiler output]

C is a 2x2 matrix, x and y are data, everything else is scalar. Why the difference in speeds between lines 33 and 34 which are both doing the same thing - assigning a scalar to an entry in an array. If I swap those two lines the behaviour is the same, the second one is much slower.

Is this a profiler bug or is there something going on I don't understand? The ratio is the same even when I scale up to several minutes (eg line 32 and line 34 take the same time). I can't see how any copy-on-write or similar would be triggered here so the speed difference doesn't make any sense to me. Saving the 30% here would be a big win for me.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Try changing those lines to `C(2) = Cxy;` and `C(3) = Cxy;` (i.e. linear indexing) in case it helps

Comment: Good idea! It makes a slight speedup (more noticeable when running outside of the profiler) but doesn't change the fact that 34 & 32 are same order of magnitude and 4x larger than 33.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason that the second one is slower, is not in the contents of the line, but more in when the matrix is actually going to be used. In the first line matlab 'knows' that it does not need to do anything yet, because the next line is an independant change in `C`.

If you want to verify that it is not in the contents of the line, add something like `C(1,1)=Cxy` underneath as a third line, probably now both of the first two lines will appear fast.

Basically this means that you can probably not not increase the speed much.

Perhaps you can try logical indexing as it may be slightly faster (untested).

```
C([false true; true false]) = Cxy;
```

or perhaps linear logical indexing:

```
C([false true true false]) = Cxy;
```

For what it is worth, I would guess that the entire effect is due to the Just In Time principle that Matlab follows.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added a third assignment but actually it is quick and the second of the Cxy assignments is still slow: http://i.imgur.com/yfYPCkg.png Also I take your point about the JIT - but I am surprised the effects could be so large... line 32 is a dot product between two 3500+ length vectors - the idea that even two scalar assignments should take the same amount of time doesn't seem plausible!

Comment: Actually the logical indexing made quite a difference to the profiler output... http://i.imgur.com/O5BdNFw.png It hasn't saved much running time outside of the profiler with larger loops, but it does make the output more sensible. Then again actually putting the two normal assignments on a single line also fixes the profiler output http://i.imgur.com/FGecOkW.png so I guess it is a bug/quirk of the profiler...

Comment: @robince the line you added in the first comment doesn't do anything, try replacing `Cx` with `Cxy` to see what happens.

Comment: the problem is if I put C(1) = Cxy the Cholesky fails because the matrix is not positive definite, so it is difficult to fairly compare the loop.